# Some actions are not being exported with the FBX file

Tags: animation, armature, export, .fbx

So I made some animations for two arms and a gun. The gun and arms are both separate armatures. The animation structure is set up like this: On the arms we have, e.g. PistolRunning, and on the pistol armature we also have PistolRunning because it needs to follow the right hand thus animate as well. When I export the whole thing, I only get 1 animation on the gun (should be equal to the animations on the arms). And the arms also do not export all actions. In blender everything plays fine, and on both armatures are the same amount of animations.

Comment: FBX files with multiple armatures are a nuisance for game engines to read. I do not know that it's even possible. Your workflow can benefit by rigging objects and animating those armatures (guns) so that other armatures (hands) can engage with them, even after being exported separately.

Comment: Right, that is what i had in mind. But my gun is already rigged and has animations, and the arms armature interacts with the gun rig correctly. However this is only the case if you set the animation on both the armatures as the same. So the arms armature animation e.g PistolShoot will only properly animate if the slide going back and forth animation (also named PistolShoot) is chosen from the gun rig action tab. I can provide the blend file if that will make things easier.